# Xdebug 3.2 with PHP 8.0 not auto detecting in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a project where I want to debug a website in the browser with the Xdebug extension. I work in PhpStorm.

Before my problem I had Xdebug 3.1.5 and PHP 8.0 and it worked with the following Xdebug configuration for the php.ini:

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger
```

Now, as I updated to Xdebug 3.2.0 the same configuration is not working...
When I remove the server in PhpStorm, there will no incoming Xdebug connection be auto detected in PhpStorm.

Is there something I need to change now with Xdebug 3.2.0?

Comment: Settings/ PHP/ Debug -> Validate debugger configuration on the Web Server

Comment: Try `xdebug.start_with_request = yes`

Comment: **1)** Check your actual/live Xdebug config first (`xdebug_info();` output) -- does it have the expected values? It may have different values for whatever reason. Make sure to check in the same environment (web server or a CLI) where you are trying to debug (as CLI and web server may use different php.ini files) **2)** Enable Xdebug log, make sure it's live and try to debug -- see what log has to say about this. Maybe it's not connecting to the right IP/port etc... **3)** Try with `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` so Xdebug tries to debug the request for sure.

Comment: Are you on Windows perhaps? There is a persistent bug where modes are not respected, but I haven't been able to reproduce this on Linux, where I have a real debugger.